# Site rankings differ by state?

Tags: ranking, local-seo

I have a friend who owns a business in CA whereas I'm in NH. I was excited to inform him that when I search for `sacramento web design` he appears on the first page rank 3.

For him, in CA, the same query has him on page 9.

I found [this article](https://microarts.com/insights/why-googles-search-results-vary-from-person-to-person/) which explains how site rankings can differ based on location and to use private browsing (we both rechecked using incognito on Chrome).

If his business is set in Sacramento and he searches for a Sacramento business that appears on page 9 for him, why would it appear on page 1 for me if it's less relevant for me?

Answer (score 1):

i guess, Google realized a personal relation between you and your friend, based on gmail, browsing history, flash cookies, contacts from your and your friend's android devices and some thousands of another factors. Thats the same cause, why i rank on place 1 for all my friends. This appearance has nothing to do with real site rankings - this is more like Google knows, what do you want to see.

Comment: I don't think it will affect when user, use browser in incognito mode, since user not logged in it's account.